# Is there a library like Python's RICH but for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to build a cli tool and I want to include nice colors and formats. Something like that I'd achieve it with [RICH](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich). But I haven't found anything like it.

The features that I'm interested are:

- print colorful log messages.
- Print tables, progress bars and spinners.
- Integration with common logging libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in your shoes before and came across this Open source library called [mordant](https://github.com/ajalt/mordant).

It basically fulfills all your needs:

- print colorful log messages. ✅
- Print tables, progress bars, and spinners. ✅
- Integration with common logging libraries. ✅

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: My question was closed but your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!